# Magnetic field sensor

Tags: signal-processing

I have an oscilloscope which measures voltage changes up to 10 Mhz analog bandwidth. My existing 30-winding search coil shows 570kHz *everywhere*, so I need a better probe to use with that oscilloscope.

I want to measure magnetic field exposure at some workstations. I don't have to fulfill TCO, I only want to compare the relative measurements.

It should integrate all 3 axes, so I don't have to be cautious about its orientation.

Comment: There are not many signal processing tags and I am not allowed to create some. Should I post on Electrical engineering stack exchange?

Comment: Yes, while writing it to be consistent with https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Then your problem is not that you are looking for a hardware, but a buggy (or buggy-looking) scope?

Comment: @peterh: I indeed look for hardware, a sensor/probe for my scope.

Comment: Okay. I suggest to make it more obvious in the question.

Answer (score 0):

https://gmw.com/product/senis-magnetic-field-transducer-3-axis-ac/ is advertised as offering three axis sensing.